# Convert integer into datetime (dd:hh:mm:ss)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT AVG (closeTime - createTime)
FROM Deals
WHERE dealid = 123
```

The 'closeTime' and 'addTime' have a DATETIME ( YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS ) format. The result is:

```
105030215.0000
```

Which function should I use to convert this value into a DATETIME?

```
addTime: 12/04/2016 13:06
closeTime:  12/05/2017 16:08
```

Result that I am looking for (which I calculated in Excel):

```
29:03:02:15 (DD:HH:MM:SS)
```

Comment: Probably something like `date('m/d/Y H:m:s', $yourQueryResult);`

Comment: @YUNOWORK It isn't a PHP question.

Comment: @hjpotter92 My bad. In MySQL, you'd probably use somethign like `FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(closeTime - createTime));`

Comment: @YUNOWORK You forgot a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtracting `DATETIME`s in MySQL does not appear to give the difference between them in seconds. With your two example dates, 2016-04-12 13:06 and 2016-05-12 16:08 (assuming the 2017 in your question is a typo), subtracting them returns 100030200 whereas the correct answer is 2602920. This is out by a factor of 38.4 and a bit.

The MySQL function to return the difference in seconds is `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and, indeed, `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-04-12 13:06', '2016-05-12 16:08')` returns the correct number of seconds.

Now all we need to do is convert it into your format. MySQL has a built-in function `SEC_TO_TIME` which **sort of** does this, but unfortunately it doesn't work for periods of more than 839 hours and it doesn't itemise the days separately. We can work around this by calculating the days separately from the rest of the calculation and using `SEC_TO_TIME` on the leftovers once the days have been subtracted from the difference.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2016-04-12 13:06', '2016-05-12 16:08'), ':',
    SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-04-12 13:06', '2016-05-12 16:08') % 86400));
-- 30:03:02:00 (DD:HH:MM:SS)
```

This appears to be the correct answer. Although your desired output was `29:03:02:15`, there were 30 days in April, and no seconds in the inputs at all.

As you're using an aggregate function to determine the number of seconds, we won't be able to select the value in days separately from the value in seconds (otherwise we'd get the average number of days followed by part of the average number of seconds), so you'll have to rewrite this as

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    FLOOR(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, createTime, closeTime)) / 86400), ':',
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, createTime, closeTime)) % 86400))
FROM deals WHERE dealid = 123;
-- 30:03:02:00.0000
```

This now includes fractions of a second because the average difference might not be a round number of seconds. To exclude them, use `FLOOR` or `ROUND`.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    FLOOR(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, createTime, closeTime)) / 86400), ':',
    SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, createTime, closeTime))) % 86400))
FROM deals WHERE dealid = 123;
```

Comment: Hi Matt, that's a pretty amazing answer, thank you for sharing the TIMESTAMPDIFF function with us, that is what it was missing for me.